# PHP : Fetching data and storing into variables

Tags: php, arrays, database

I wanted to fetch the data from the database and wants to store into an array and after storing the data into the array i want to access particular index of the array.
I'm a java developer need to do this in php (which I don't know much).
Basically there are 250 strings in a table i wanted to fetch those 250 strings into and array and wants to access some particular row.
 for example :

```
 <?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

**$uname100 = $row[100]; // this is not getting assigned to $uname100 variable**
**echo $row[100]; // here this is not printing** 
**echo $uname100; // not even this printing**
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Please check the bold part in the code and help me out. I'm new to php so please dont panic over this.

And also wanted to do something like this :

```
$ctr=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
$uname[$ctr++] = $row['FirstName']; // AND USING THIS OUTSIDE LOOP
}

echo $uname[90];
```

Comment: put `print_r($row);` after the end of `while` and see your array contains with your `index` key what you defined? Also update with question

Answer (score 0):

Use array construction

```
$counter=0;
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   $data[] = $row['FirstName'];
   $counter++;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Where you could use `$counter`? Does it only for counter part?

Comment: i want to print only particular index so print_r($data) will not work.. I want to get all data into an array and then I have to use e.g 5th index of array echo $data[5];

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable $row[100] outside the while loop.
Also $row will not contain an index 100.
It will be containing only $row['FirstName'] or $row['LastName'] inside the while loop

Answer for second part:

```
$uname = array();
$ctr=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ....
  ....

  $uname[$ctr++] = $row['FirstName']; // AND USING THIS OUTSIDE LOOP
}

if(isset($uname[90])) echo $uname[90];
```

Comment: my mistake.. try this: if(isset($uname[90])) echo $uname[90];

Answer (score 0):

First solution

```
$counter=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$counter++;
$varName='uname'.$counter;
$$varName=$row['FirstName'];
}

echo echo $uname100;
```

Comment: why posting senseless solution